# Handling an external dialog return with commandLink

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandlink

After much hair-pulling, I am finally able to open a full html page as a dialog box. I'm doing this with a commandLink as the button needs to be a clickable image. 
Unfortunately it seems that commandLink does not handle the "returnDialog" event. 
What would be a convenient way do get hold of the data from the dialog in this case ?

```
<h:form>

        <h:commandLink id="pdf" actionListener="#{testBean.viewSelector}">
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="icon_pdf.png" />
            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" etc.. /><!-- This does not work -->
        </h:commandLink>

        <p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{testBean.viewSelector}">
            <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{testBean.onPageSelectionSubmitted}" /><!-- This one does but I don't want a button -->
        </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

EDIT version + implementation info :

- primefaces 5.3
- JSF 2.2, mojarra

Comment: Version info? PF and JSF/Impl

Comment: I edited in the version info